# Remove the new Copilot search icon from the Windows 11 task bar

Tags: windows, taskbar, bing

This new Copilot Preview icon just showed up in my taskbar. How do I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Right-click the taskbar and choose Settings. Right at the top, under taskbar items, there's a new switch to disable Copilot (preview).

[image]